# Convert a traditional post in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Suppose I have a form :

```
<form id="myForm" method="POST" action="/something/somewhere">
   <input type="text" name="textField" />
   <input type="submit" name="foo" value="bar" />
</form>
```

the `/something/somewhere` action does not return a complete html page, but just a fragment.

I would like to let the submit button do its posting job, but catch the result of this post and inject it somewhere in the DOM.

The jQuery `submit` happens *before* the form is actually submitted. An exemple of how it could work is:

```
$('#myForm').posted(function(result)
{
    $('#someDiv').html(result);
});
```

Any way to do this?

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Description

You can use the jQuery `.post()` and `.serialize()` method for that.

> **.post()** Load data from the server using a HTTP POST request.
>
> **.serialize()** Encode a set of form elements as a string for submission.
>
> **.preventDefault()** If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered. *In your case the normal submit.*

#### Sample

**Html**

```
<form id="myForm" method="POST" action="/My/MyActionMethod">
   <input type="text" name="textField" />
   <input type="submit"/>
</form>

<div id="someDiv"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $('#myForm').live('submit', function (e) {
     var form = $(this);
     e.preventDefault();
     $.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize(), function (result) {
        $('#someDiv').html(result);
     });
  });
});
```

**MVC Controller**

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyActionMethod(FormCollection forms)
    {
        // do something with forms["textField"];
        return Content("<b>Hello World!</b>");
    }
}
```

If you have trouble getting it to work (thanks IE), try

```
event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
```

#### More Information

- [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)
- [jQuery.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)
- [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Comment: And then add your callback as the third parameter of $.post

Comment: @Tom my answer is extended. Thank You!

Comment: @Johnny5, "e.preventDefault();" from dknaack's answer is the important part--it will stop the normal form submission. If you have trouble getting it to work (thanks IE), try

event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;

Comment: Thx @jnunn. I updated my answer with your comment. And upvoted you comment. Nice!

Comment: The comment in question was not mine, it's @jnunn.

Comment: @Johnny5 right ;) But my comment to jnunn was right :) my mistake.. it is changed. Does my answer help you ?

Comment: @jnunn: jQuery will unify the event methods and properties. No need to handle browser differences yourself.

Comment: I edited the answer with my exact solution, waiting for review.

Comment: @Johnny5 Thanks!! I have updated my answer with your stuff, changed html and the ActionMethod, i think we have done a great job! All the best!

Comment: @dknaack Funny that you guess that I'm using asp.net MVC even if I did not mentionned it, but you're right ;-)

Comment: @Johnny5 ;) I don't think about that. I just saw ASP.NET and the extensionless URL. Great job! Thanks again! ;) I add the ASP.NET MVC Tag to your question now.

Answer (score 1):

While you can hack a simple example yourself using [`.post`](http://api.jquery.com/post/) and [`.serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/), if you want to do anything more than trivial, I'd suggest looking into [this plugin](https://github.com/malsup/form), which is (from what github and the project page says) actively community-maintained by the jQuery folks.